# How to directly set mediaStream into a video tag?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

How can I directly without using `useRef` or selecting the `element` in the HTML insert a `mediaStream` into a HTML video tag?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to get the mediaStream track to insert the src into the HTML video track. So you probably need to render again the component after you get the info of the user mediaStream.